# Joomla Site was Slow

Tags: joomla, server, web, ram, hypervisor

I have project to create elearning website using joomla and there are videos and many images in my site .i used hypervisor as server with Specification Processor : 1 Core Intel Xeon E5640 , Memory: 4 GB , when 50 user accessed my site , the loading page was too slow. any recomendation server for my site?

Answer (score 0):

It won't necessarily be your server. Unless you have taken the appropriate steps to reduce images and videos they could be reduced by 70%, this will instantly speed things up

check out the following

[Tiny Jpg](https://tinyjpg.com/)

[Tiny Png](https://tinypng.com/)

Also google how to reduce video size.

Look at a CDN (cross distribution network) to serve your content locally

Also Sprite maps and optimization for repeated elements like Buttons etc.

Use CSS to replace things like buttons.